# Saturn SL1 1998 Wiring Diagram

Tags: wiring, saturn, sl1

I'm in search of wiring diagram of Saturn SL1 1998.

My car does not fire-up anymore, and everything indicate that the interlock has stopped working which stop my car from starting.

I want to remove the interlock, however I'd like to have the wiring diagram before doing this to avoid any further problem...

Also if anyone know any good web sites where are stored diagrams please post them as I searched a lot but couldn't find any "good" one.

Edit : If you have any other idea how I could bypass interlock without removing it, feel free to post them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why bypass instead of fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same car, I bought it new, I've had to replace the fuss/relay panel on the passenger side under the glove box twice... The internal hard wiring of the panel melts and burns at the power source for the fuel pump fuse...